# How can I get root Password via API against VM instance on Softlayer?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I used "psl vs detail  --passwords" to query the passwords of the VM instance. Then filter out the root password.
However, currently May 1st, 2018, it seems this API has been changed. The output of the above cmd does not contain the password anymore.
If so, what API can I use to get the root password?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. The root cause is that SL add new user permission control to "View Customer Software Password". By default it was not enabled. 
After enable this permission to the api user, the password could be read.